# WPF binding and Contexts

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've got an issue binding a code behind string property for a column header. The header is always an empty string when running the application.

```
<UserControl [...]
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >    
    <c:DataGrid Name="m_dataGrid"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}" >

        <c:DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Column 'Importieren/Exportieren' -->
            <c:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto"
                                      MinWidth="100">
                <c:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="m_checkBoxExportAllDefinitions"
                                  Content="{Binding ImportExportColumnHeader, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </c:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <c:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsDefinitionExportEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </c:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </c:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </c:DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see, the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` is being set onto itself and the `ItemsSource` of the data grid is being set to Configurations, which is this code behind property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ImportExportConfiguration> Configurations { get; private set; }
```

When setting a break point in the code behind property used to bind the header text (defined in the `HeaderTemplate`), the getter is never being called:

```
public string ImportExportColumnHeader {
   get {
      return IsImport ? ErgaenzungsfelderResources.ImportExportSelectionControlImportierenColumnHeader :
         ErgaenzungsfelderResources.ImportExportSelectionControlExportierenColumnHeader;
   }
}
```

The binding for the `CellTemplate` onto `IsDefinitionExportEnabled` works. This is a property contained in the `ImportExportConfiguration` class, whereas `ImportExportColumnHeader` isn't.

I suppose wpf tries to get the `ImportExportColumnHeader` property from `ImportExportConfiguration` where it doesn't exist; that's why it displays an empty header. Is this correct?

How can the code behind property be accessed?

Comment: it looks like the dataContext of the usercontrol is being set to itself. Remove the datacontext and try again. Also chekc the output window for binding errors

Comment: @user1 I want to bind it this way to be able to bind to the code behind properties. Removing the `DataContext` breaks the binding of the `CellTemplate`. I think the problem arises because I want to bind the HeaderTemplate (which is the same for all bound items) onto a code behind property and the `CellTemplate` (which is different for all bound items) onto a property contained in `Configurations`.

Comment: @user1 The outupt window doesn't show any binding errors

Comment: in that case the binding is fine. I think the problem lies with the ImportExportColumnHeader. You should probably have this as a get / set property raising propertychanged

Comment: @user1 I've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire `OnPropertyChanged("ImportExportColumnHeader")` when `ImportExportColumnHeader` changes (it is now being called when `IsImport`is being set). The header remains empty and the getter is still not being called!?

Comment: To rule out a problem with the XAML template, comment out the `<HeaderTemplate>` block and add `Header="{Binding ImportExportColumnHeader}"` to the `<c:DataGridTemplateColumn ...`. Does the text appear in the column header with this?

Comment: @AndrewStephens The answer I've posted fixes the issue. It seems weird that the source was wrong, but no binding exceptions were shown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the correct source solved my issue:

```
<CheckBox Name="m_checkBoxExportAllDefinitions"
          Content="{Binding ImportExportColumnHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type importExport:ImportExportSelectionControl}}}" />
```